# I want to get specific values inside multiple Objects in One array using forEach or a loop in PHP

Tags: php, loops, foreach

Here is my data :

```
$data = [{"5": "4"}, {"10": "0"}, {"6": "1"}, {"11": "0"}, {"7": "0"}, {"1": "10"}, {"2": "5"}, {"8": "3"}, {"12": "0"}, {"3": "0"}, {"9": "0"}, {"4": "2"}];
```

What I want to do is to loop inside this array and be able to get the first value and the second of each object inside the Array

Comment: I'm sending an array from a react native application using fetch and the result in the server is like this, first answer is working, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
   foreach($data as $entry) {
      foreach($entry as $key => $value) {
         echo "Key: " . $key . "<br>Value: " . $value . "<br><br>";
      }
   }
?>
```

Comment: Not working, I need a way to get inside of the objects, for example: $data[2] is giving {"6": "1"}, but how to access those elements inside of it ?? $data[2][0] is null

Comment: Ohh its a dictionary. A sec.

Comment: You can skip the inner foreach and use `$key = array_key_first($entry);` and `$value = $entry[$key];` instead.